# unable to post an image to twitter using sharekit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sharekit

Im using ShareKit for posting to Twitter and Facebook in my app. Facebook is working fine.

But when i tried to post on twitter firstly the message "saved" is showing and then immediately the alert message" Error unknown error" is showing and the message is not get posted in twitter.

Can anyone please help me with this.

I googled a lot and cant figure out the problem.

Hope for your help.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Concern is your sharkit might not be update. 
    So check below Setting, we need to change SHKTwitter.m in lines 54-56 from

Make Changes `https://twitter.com/` to `https://api.twitter.com/`

```
self.authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"];
self.requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];
self.accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token"];
```

Then, in sendStatus method update the URL link u have to use `https` instead `of http`:

```
OAMutableURLRequest *oRequest = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"] consumer:consumer token:accessToken realm:nil signatureProvider:nil];
```

Make this changes you will be able share image and post in share kit

**EDIT** : Refer [this](http://jayrparro.posterous.com/incorrect-signature-sharekittwitter-error) link for more information.

Comment: check api key , consumer and secret key or reset the keys at https://dev.twitter.com/ and change keys in sharekit

Comment: thanks..it works for me now .. i took the latest sharekit from github and made changes as you mentioned above ..

Answer (score 2):

make sure you use updated [shareKit 2.0](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit). Follow [new install guide](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) precisely, as it is little different than [original sharekit](http://www.getsharekit.com/).